# how do i fix "undefined variable"

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH18m.png)transaction.blade

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="visually-hidden" for="mechanic_id">Mechanic</label>
                        <select name="mechanic_id" class="form-control form-select" id="mechanic_id" required>
                            @foreach ($mechanic as $item)
                                @if (old('mechanic') == $item->id)
                                    <option value="{{ $item->id }}" selected>{{ $item->nama }}</option>
                                @else
                                    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->nama }}</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG2EP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBvlV.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What's the undefined variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace if condition variable with name attribute of select tag.

```
 @if (old('mechanic') == $item->id)
```

**replace by**

```
 @if (old('mechanic_id') == $item->id)
```

Comment: still undefined bruh

Comment: please send a image picture of error. I need to know what is undefined.

Comment: how I send image in this comment?

Comment: Please Attach in question or online make a url of image and send it in comment